# Selecting the last entry of each day in a timestamp and corresponding value

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following table "test",

[image]

Let the data in the table be as follows,

[image]

Now I want to select last entry (only date not the timestamp) for each day and corresponding value as two columns. one being the date and other being the value.

I am able to fetch  only the date using the following query,

```
SELECT max( date( date ) ) AS date
FROM test
GROUP BY date( date )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But am not being able to get the corresponding values for those dates.
How can I do it..? By googling, I came to know that I have to use join to achieve this, but again I couldn't use join without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the column name from the reserved keyword `date` to something that doesn't need quoting:

```
ALTER TABLE test
    CHANGE COLUMN `date` timestamp_entered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
                         --- or some other sensible name
```

Then you could use:

```
SELECT
    grp.date_entered  
  , t.value 
FROM 
        test  AS t
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT 
            , DATE( timestamp_entered )  AS date_entered
              MAX( timestamp_entered )   AS max_timestamp
          FROM 
              test
          GROUP BY
              DATE( timestamp_entered )
        ) 
          AS grp 
      ON 
          grp.max_timestamp = t.timestamp_entered
```

Comment: I changed the column as u said, and tried your query. am getting this error----------------  #1630 - FUNCTION t.DATE does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: Did you try the query as it is? I don't have a `t.DATE` anywhere.

Comment: Ah, you probably have a space between `DATE` and `(`: `DATE ( ...`. Just remove it.

Comment: Perfect...!! Thank you so much..:) by the way, `t.DATE` was there the last time I copied from...!!..:) anyway, It worked..:)

Comment: Oh, and my `ALTER TABLE` probably made the column Nullable. Change it back to `NOT NULL`.

Comment: there is another problem..!! I want to select only the date part from the timestamp not the entire timestamp. how can I do it..?? If I use the query I written in the question, it says "Zero rows returned"..! So its not exactly what am looking for..:(

Comment: Edited the answer. But it would be a simple use of `DATE()` function in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Join your query to the original table:

```
SELECT
  baseview.`date` AS `date`,
  `test`.`value` AS `value`
FROM `test`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(date) AS date
    FROM test
    GROUP BY date( date )
    LIMIT 0 , 30 
  ) AS baseview ON `test`.`date`=baseview.`date`
```

Comment: You probably wanted `max(date)` instead of `max( date( date ) )`.

Comment: am getting this error------------- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` AS `value` FROM `test`, INNER JOIN ( SELECT max( date( date ) ) AS date ' at line 3

Comment: No actually, this is just a test table for my actual application, I need only the date and the value. Its actually to plot a graph.

Comment: do u mean double quote for test right..?? But its giving the same error..! Can u please write the corrected query..??

Comment: Hey.. I got it didn't see that double quote the first time..:p Its not showing any error , at the same time its not fetching either..! It says "zero rows returned"...!

Comment: @EugenRieck , also there should be a comma after `date` on line 1 not a full stop (it gives an error)..! But still am NOT getting any results..it still says, "Zero rows returned"..! what's wrong..??

Comment: OK, fixed the fullstop AND fixed the `data( date )` which should be the reason for no rows. Please retry. Sorry, I have a bad cold and simply don't see the difference between a fullstop and a comma

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
SELECT t2 . * 
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN test t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY DATE( t1.date ) 
ORDER BY t1.date
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It simply retrieve the <strike>max</strike> (*edit* : first) date (for all day), and select info for each row.

Comment: But its selecting the first entry for the day and its value not the last entry for the day.

Comment: You are right, then @Eugen Rieck answer is better than mine :)

Comment: As I commented on his answer, am getting that error..! I dont know wats wrong.